# How to use part specification as a function

Tags: functions

I need to define elements of a matrix as functions; For instance the element "Q_nk" of the matrix "Q", to be defined as:

Part[Q, n_, k_] := ...

So, I cannot do that and receive the error message "n_ cannot be used as part specification". So, does anyone know how to manage this? Any help and guide is really appreciated.

Regards,
Marilla.

Comment: What exactly is the code you tried?

Comment: it's rather long, but nothing wrong is there actually.

Comment: `Part` is a built-in function, you mustn't  define anything like this `Part[Q, n_, k_] :=` unless you write `part` however you don't need to play with it since you have `Part`.

Comment: so, assuming I need to do something like: Part[Q,n_,k_]:=n+k; how should I define this?

Comment: or more generally said, if I need to define a matrix that each of its elements is a function of a couple of variables, how can I do that?

Comment: and if later i need to "access" Part[Q,n,k]?

Comment: @Marilla, "if I need to define a matrix that each of its elements is a function of a couple of variables, how can I do that?" Are you looking for something like `Table[f[i,j],{i,1,10},{j,1,10}]`? This will give a 10x10 matrix where each element is `f[i,j]`, some function of the indices.

Comment: And if it's a sparse array, you could do something like `SparseArray[
  Flatten[
   Table[{i, j} -> i^2 + j^3, {i, Range[1, 10, 2]}, {j, 
     Range[1, 10, 3]}], 1]
  ] // MatrixForm`

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Try this:

```
q[matr_, n_, k_] := matr[[n, k]];
```

Now let us take a matrix:

```
m = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
```

and apply the function to this matrix:

```
 q[m, 1, 2]

(*   b   *)
```

Done, have fun!

Comment: Many thanks Alexei for your guide and consideration; Actually, what i need is slightly different in a way that I generate the matrix "m" with all "0" elements and then I need to define its elements as functions (depending on the elements, functions maybe different): So, i need something like: q[matr_, n_, k_] := matr[[n, k]]=Sum[...]; 

Later, I need to use this matrix in some calculations.

Comment: It seems something like this works:

f[Q_, n_, k_] := f[Q, n, k] = Part[Q, n, k] = n + k;
Q = Table[0*n*k, {n, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}]
Q[[1, 1]] = f[Q, 1, 1]

Comment: @Marilla You cannot make such constructs as `f[Q_, n_, k_] := f[Q, n, k] = Part[Q, n, k] = n + k; Q = Table[0*n*k, {n, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}] Q[[1, 1]] = f[Q, 1, 1]`.   They are illegal. You should use `:=`  or  `=`  only once in the expression. It would be helpful, if you describe in details an example of what you are after. Then it will be more clear, what solution to offer.

Comment: Dear Alexei,
Many thanks for you reply and guide; So, I'll try to manage it and if cannot will post here again.